# Resize box and content on hover

Tags: css

Alright so I was trying transitions and I wondered if it was possible with only css to resize a box (div) and it's content at the same time so everything would grow instead of only the box growing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay actually solved this myself, it's as easy as using transform: scale(X.x);